# RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource throwing an exception

Tags: azure, resources, directory, azure-web-roles

I had a cloud service hosted on Azure that I now want transffed to an Azure VM which hosts many applications. I have moved this and everything is working as expected except for file upload. On upload of a file I was previously using the following code:

```
LocalResource lr = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("TempZipDirectory");
```

As I have now moved the project to Inetpub folder of the VM this is no longer working as it is outside of the role environment.

How can I write the content to a tempdirectory on the VM?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the concept of `LocalResource` is only applicable when your application is deployed as a `Cloud Service (PaaS)`. If you're deploying your application in a `Virtual Machine (IaaS)`, you are not restricted where you could write on the VM's file system thus the concept of local resource is not applicable.

As far as writing goes, it would be the same way you would write in case your application is hosted in a VM/Server in your premises.

Comment: Correct, the "RoleEnvironment" is a PaaS construct and not available in IaaS.

Comment: The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx page says The RoleEnvironment class can be used on standalone components in an Azure VM outside of an Azure role. These components can be programs that can be run by, for example, remoting into the role instance and starting the component from the command line. These processes must be run with elevated privileges to access the RoleEnvironment class.